# Group Homomorphism: Kernel, Image, quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G \xrightarrow{\phi} H$ be a group homomorphism.

(a) Prove that the kernel of $\phi$ is a normal subgroup of G.

(b) Prove that the image of $\phi$ is a subgroup of H.

(c) Prove that there is a group isomorphism between the quotient group $G / \ker\phi$ and the image of $\phi$.

Comment: Hints: a: Try the definition???

Comment: b) Again, verify the definition. c) map g->gK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a)$

I write $f$ for $\phi$. We need to prove that: $\forall g\in G, \forall h\in\ker(f):ghg^{-1}\in \ker(f)$

Let $g\in G$ and let $h\in\ker(f)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
f(ghg^{-1})&=f(g)f(h)f(g)^{-1} &&f \text{ is an homomorphism}\\ 
&=f(g)e_2f(g)^{-1} &&h\in\ker(f)\\
&=e_2 &&f(g)f(g)^{-1}=e_2
\end{align*}

By defintion of the kernel, then $ghg^{-1} \in \ker(f)$.

Answer (score -1):

These are in the text by Fraleigh, *A first course in Abstract algebra* 7ed, for 1 see Theorem 13.15 and Cor. 13.20. For 2 see T. 13.12 and for 3 see T. 14.1.